# How specific are the requirements for images submitted to create Irish passport cards?

Tags: biometric-passports, irish-citizens

Trying to get an Irish passport card but I hear so many people say that images that are approved on the website are rejected because they don't meet requirements.

I'm just wondering, are the requirements higher than those for an Irish passport book?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm just wondering, are the requirements higher than those for an
>   Irish passport book?

No, they are exactly the same.

From the [Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade Passport Card page](https://www.dfa.ie/passportcard/):

> You can find more information on how to apply for your passport card and photo guidelines on our online passport application page.

And those guidelines are the same for both passports and passport cards:

[Guidelines for photos taken by professionals](https://www.dfa.ie/passportonline/photographerguidelines/)

[Guidelines for photos taken by applicants](https://www.dfa.ie/passportonline/onlinephotoguidelines/)

[General FAQs for photos](https://www.dfa.ie/passportonline/onlinefaqs/)